# org-publish: publish exactly files in a given list

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-publish

I have hundreds Org files under a directory hierarchy and would want to export *only* those recently modified in HTML to speed up the process. I have the following project alist that I feed up to `org-publish`:

```
`("html"
       :base-directory        "~/Org/wiki"
       :base-extension        "org"
       :include               ,(my/org-files-to-publish)
       :with-broken-links     t
       :publishing-directory  "~/Org/wiki"
       :publishing-function   org-html-publish-to-html)
```

where `(my/org-files-to-publish)` returns recent Org files to export.

It seems that `org-publish` considers not only files of `:include` but also unconditionally those immediately under the root directory (*e.g.* `~/Org/wiki` here).

**Question**: How to export exactly a list of Org files to HTML ?

As `:exclude` accepts only regex and not a files list, I can't find a reliable way to do what I want beside looping on `(my/org-files-to-publish)` using `org-publish-file` plus some extra stuff `org-publish-projects` does.

P.S. This theory is confirmed by checking the output of `set-difference :test 'equal` between `org-publish-get-base-files PROJECT` and `(my/org-files-to-publish)`.

Comment: `my/org-files-to-publish` is only called once above: when you define `org-publish-project-alist` in the first place. Once that has been done, the `:include` list is set for the duration of the session. So the problem is *NOT* how to export exactly a list of Org files: you do that by setting the `:include` property. Your problem seems to be: how to dynamically *change* the `:include` property so that its value is the result of the function call. Am I understanding the problem correctly?

Comment: @NickD Thanks for the comment. In fact, I do not use `org-publish-project-alist`, I use a project alist that I feed up to `org-publish`whenever I'm publishing. So `my/org-files-to-publish` is called each time, and the list of files indeed changes dynamically. I print the list length to make sure this really happens. Now, no matter what list I'm exporting, it always exports and start by the first-level files unconditionally (even if the list doesn't include them). And this is because `org-publish-projects` (called by `org-publish`) includes them by calling `org-publish-get-base-files`.

Comment: In my understanding, the documentation is not wrong, because it didn't say it `:include` those files exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

According to `org-publish-project-alist` documentation (emphasis mine):

> The :include property may be used to include **extra** files.

This means that your project alist will match all org files in your directory plus any files included via `:include` property.

You can achieve desired result in somewhat hacky way by setting `:base-extension` to a dummy value that won't match any files:

```
`("html"
       :base-directory        "~/Org/wiki"
       :base-extension        "dummy"
       :include               ,(my/org-files-to-publish)
       :with-broken-links     t
       :publishing-directory  "~/Org/wiki"
       :publishing-function   org-html-publish-to-html)
```